# Express + MQTT from POST request to publish in topic

Tags: node.js, express, post, mqtt

I need a Node.js web service that accept a specific POST request that will trigger a publishing in a specific MQTT topic.
I use Express to listen for the request and this part of the script works fine. 
The problem is when I it should trigger the publish in topic to perform a downlink. 
The code without the Express part works fine. So It seems like Express interfere with MQTT. But the connection to the Broker works fine. Only the publish procedure doesn't work.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
const util = require('util')


var app = express();

var CERT = //certificate
var PORT = //port
var HOST = // host

var options = {
   port: PORT,
   host: HOST,
   clientId: //client_id
   username: //uname
   password: //pswd
   cert: CERT,
   rejectUnauthorized: false,
   protocol: 'mqtts'
}
var client;
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
})

client = mqtt.connect(options);

client.on("connect", () => {
   console.log("MQTT connected");
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
   var msg = JSON.parse(message)
   console.log("topic: " + topic + " msg:" + util.inspect(msg))
});


app.post('/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
   // Prepare output in JSON format
   data = {
      dev_id: req.body.dev_id,
      pswd: req.body.password,
      tx_cycle: req.body.tx_cycle
   };
   if (data.pswd != "password") {
      console.log("Wrong password")
   }
   else {
      console.log(data);
      var topic = 'publish_topic';
      var tx_cy = data.tx_cycle;
      var msg = '{"port":"222","payload":"' + tx_cy + '","confirmed": false,"window":"BOTH","priority":0}';
      console.log('Try to send downlink message, for ' + data.dev_id + ' set to ' + data.tx_cycle + ' min -> hex ' + tx_cy);
      client.subscribe('reply/+/id/+');

      client.publish(topic, msg);
      res.status(200).send(msg + " sent to broker");
   }
});



var server = app.listen(port, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: Why are you subscribing in the post handler? That would be better done once from in the `client.on('connect',...)` callback.  Wrap the call to `client.publish()` in a try catch block to see if/why it's failing. There is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. I was trying different alternatives to understand the problem. Now I managed to solve the problem

Comment: There is no need to edit the question to mark it as resolved. Just come back and mark your own answer as accepted as this will make it easier to find in search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem. The client id was refused by the broker because was not unique. Changing it solved the issue.

Comment: Client id's need to be globally unique, if you have 2 clients with the same client id then the fist one will be disconnected as the second connects. If you have auto reconnect enabled then they will repeatedly kick each other off.